# Need to get action url by action name in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, breadcrumbs

I am new to Struts2. I have to create breadcrumbs in an application so what I want to do is to set a Map with all label/url of all links in breadcrumbs. My problem is that I don't know how to get the URL of an action inside the action class.

eg.

```
private Map<String, String> breadcrumbs;

public String MyAction() throws Exception {

    breadcrumbs.put("List", SomeClass.getUrl("listAction"));
    breadcrumbs.put("Project", SomeClass.getUrl("projectAction"));
    breadcrumbs.put("Chart", SomeClass.getUrl("chartProjectAction"));

    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

So, what should I use instead of that SomeClass to get the Url of an action?

Thanks in advance,
Ciprian

Comment: So you have an action name and want to get an url for this action name? What you gonna do with this map afterwards?

Comment: I want to print all these links in the header of the page to enable user to go up in the application structure. In fact I want to be able to get the url from the action name, like the <s:url action="actionName" /> tag does using action attribute.

Comment: But why do you need it in action class? Put just action names and in JSP use `<s:url>` tag to generate urls.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I've done eventually. Being a beginner, I don't connect all things from the start. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW you can answer your own question to help future visitors with same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, as Aleksandr M suggests, I've send from the Action the action names and compile the URL directly from the .jsp file using s:url tag

```
<s:iterator value="breadcrumbs" status="st">
    <s:if test="#st.last == true">
        <li class="active"><s:property value="key" /></li>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <li><a href="<s:url action="%{value}" />"><s:property value="key" /></a></li>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

Hope this will help someone!